# How can I speed up encoding GIFs using "image"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently trying to use [`encodeGifAnimation`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/encodeGifAnimation.html) from the [`image` package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) in Flutter.
Something tells me that the implementation is flawed because it prints the following about 15 thousand times when trying to encode a GIF with less than 100 frames and a resolution of less than 250000 pixels (very small):

```
runtime.gc collection time 15,189ms • 103.5MB used of 118.6MB • isolates/2265278053616199
```

Anyway, this is my only choice as it looks like, so I would like to optimize the time it takes. I have a feeling that the `15k` prints to the log impact the performance quite a bit.

Is there a way to disable these print statements from the garbage collector?
Even when running regular Flutter apps, the garbage collector print statements are annoying.

Comment: "Even when running regular Flutter apps, the garbage collector print statements are annoying." - I never get any print statements from the garbage collector. Are you sure you haven't enabled that somewhere to start with?

Comment: @Ovidiu It certainly depends on what you are doing with Flutter. Working with scroll views and images *should* trigger garbage collection, otherwise you are probably leaking memory by holding the references somewhere. It seems like only larger garbage collections are reported then.

Comment: I have searched the logs for 'runtime.gc' and nothing comes up even during the most memory intensive operations, such as taking photos, taking videos, displaying several thumbnails at once, or encrypting and decrypting entire files. I'm even more convinced now than I was before that you have enabled those kind of logs somehow as they don't exist by default.

Comment: Are you using the web-based DevTools Logging by any chance? That seems to be the only log printing GC-related messages, as per https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/logging . If that's the case you should have mentioned it in your question - the majority of Flutter developers use either the Flutter log within the IDE, or the native logs also in the IDE (eg. the Logcat on Android)

Comment: @Ovidiu I am using the Android Studio logs and it should not really matter if it is displayed or not because it impacts performance even when you do not see it. I really do not know why you do not see it, but I know that it is a basic part of Flutter, so it is not at all strange to see it.

Comment: @Ovidiu It seems like this is something that only happens in Android Studio logs. You mentioned that you could not see it and `flutter run` does not show it either, not even in verbose mode.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the image library beeing created for web. See the open issues of the library, there are multiple reports about bad performance when used with flutter. The creator never worked with flutter.

Comment: @ZeRj Yes, I am aware of the fact that it was created for web and it is also very old. Later compatibility was added for Dart 2.0 and with that for Flutter. Anyways, there is no other image library and before I implement encoding GIFs myself, I would rather try to optimize the performance of `image` in my Flutter app. I know that GIF encoding is not too hard, but it is extremely cumbersome to find out where to put which bytes to get a correct result. If nobody here knows how to deal with this issue, I might just try to adjust the implementation from the package.

Comment: @ZeRj I forgot to mention [`gifencoder`](https://pub.dev/packages/gifencoder), which is what I used first, but that does not support **opacity** (?) and this one is actually *made* for web in the sense that it works best with the HTML canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a quantization issue, which can now be fixed by supplying a `samplingFactor`. See [the documentation](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/blob/5197317748a324dae453374c56f74236789d7bdc/lib/src/formats/formats.dart#L258) for reference.

Until the [pull request](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/pull/152) is merged, adding the following to your `pubspec.yaml` will allow you to use it:

```
dependency_overrides:
  image:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image
      ref: 10504002bd8d62f79b77593ddbb537e25b0d29fa
```

Answer (score -1):

I would go for tuning the log level.

```
Logger.level = Level.verbose;
```

Comment: This class does not exist for me. Maybe you mean that I should use [this plugin](https://github.com/dart-lang/logging)? And how would this solve my problem? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I tested the plugin and I can confirm that this answer is complete nonsense as neither `Logger.level` exists in the plugin (only `Logger.root.level`) nor `Level.verbose`. There are `Level`'s, but even if I set `Logger.root.level = Level.NONE`, this does not disable the garbage collection logging statements. Whoever gave this an upvote, please explain to me what this should mean if OP does not..